# What does IRenderFunction interface definition mean in FluentUI?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm new to typescript and have started to working with `DetailsList` in Fluent UI.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist.

I am looking into the prop `onRenderRow` which is of type `IRenderFunction`.

https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/utilities/src/IRenderFunction.ts

Here, I understand that `props` is of the generic type `P` and `defaultRender` is a function with `props` as argument and returns `JSX.Element or null` type. But what does parentheses around both of these mean? Is it a function type? How should an implementation of this interface look like?

`(props?: P, defaultRender?: (props?: P) => JSX.Element | null)`

This as a whole is also returning `JSX.Element or null` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function *with two parameters* `props` and `defaultRender`.

> But what does parentheses around both of these mean? Is it a function type?

**Yes! Return value of that function is** `JSX.Element or null`.

First parameter `props` is generic type `P` and the second one `defaultRender` is a **function** with one parameter `props` generic type `P` which returns `JSX.Element | null`.

Here you are an example how to change a background color of row:

```js
<DetailsList
  ...
  onRenderRow={(props, defaultRender) => {
    // props and defaultRender could be undefined
    if (props && defaultRender) {
      return defaultRender({
        ...props,
        styles: {
          ...props.styles,
          root: {
            backgroundColor: '#f00',
          }
        }
      })
    }
    return null;
  }}
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/PoOxrpp?editors=0010) working example.